# WebMethod with optional parameter doesn't work in client side

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I write a webmethod with optional parameter.

```
[WebMethod]
  public void EmailSend(string from, string to, string cc = null, string bcc = null, string replyToList = null, string subject = null, string body = null, bool isBodyHtml = false , string[] attachmentNames = null, byte[][] attachmentContents = null)
    {
     .....
    }
```

I call this method in client side application

```
 EmailServiceManagement.EmailService es = new EmailServiceManagement.EmailService();
 es.EmailSend(from, to,null,null,null,subject,body,true,attName,att); //this works
```

but

```
es.EmailSend(from,to); // this isn't working. According to c# optional parameter syntax it must work.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Web methods should be platform/language independent and every language doesn't have to support optional parameters. So your first version is correct.

Comment: @I4V So It doesn't make any sense to use optional parameters in web methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have optional parameters on WebMethods. What you can do is have overloaded methods like this:

```
[WebMethod(MessageName="Test")]
public string GenerateMessage(string firstName)
{
   return string.Concat("Hi ", firstName);
}

[WebMethod(MessageName="AnotherTest")]
public string GenerateMessage(string firstName, string lastName)
{
   return string.Format("Hi {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
}
```

Not sure exactly how you're interacting with this WebMethod but having so many parameters is probably an indication that you can group them in an object something like:

```
[WebMethod]
public void EmailSend(MessageParameters messageParams)
{
     .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know overloaded methods, I want to know is really optional parameters doesn't work on webmethods or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Nope, they just don't work.

Comment: Why was I downvoted ? Care to comment ? Is the solution wrong ? I would like to know if I did a mistake, thank you.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov I missed the `MessageName` part. If you edit your answer I will upvote.